# How to run two different test cases at the same time in one virtual machine

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

*I want to run multiple test cases in one virtual agent machine in parallel.* i.e. all test case should start executing at the same time in a single machine. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: At the same time with the same browser?

Comment: yes. And if you can do with different browsers please tell. Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try anything and what didn't work? How are you running your tests? Which languages are you using to write them?

Comment: I have automated test cases using selenium C# and I am right now running the test cases all at the same time and those test cases run on agent machine one by one.

Comment: Is there any way that I can run those test cases two or three at the same time in same browser or different browser on one(same) agent machine?